# Excel increment row by 1

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet where the first column contains the text "user_#" in each row. 
I need to replace the "#" in each row and rep[lace it with the row number such that
user_1
user_2
user_3
'
'
'
user_n

Is there a simple function that I can plug into the first row and then copy and drag so that each row will be filled in correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, where B3 is a cell on the same row as the one where you're putting this formula.

```
 =CONCATENATE("USER_",ROW(B3))
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Helped to build a user name: User_#@hostname.com

Answer (score 3):

you could simply have the text "user 1" in the first row and drag down then column. You need to choose the fill type to "fill series" in the "Auto Fill Options" box which appears when you drag down the column

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can `="USER_"&ROW(B3)` as an alternative.  If you need a special format, like integer, you can make sure you get what you want by using this `="USER_"&TEXT(ROW(B3),"#")`.  Of course, this might be too much if you are using ROW().  I just added it in in case you wanted to reference a non-integer value.